# how can I create multiple circle layout of images using js and css

Tags: javascript, html, css

Similarly to the screenshot, I am trying to create a circle of images that includes another circle of images within a circle, and I already created it using two elements, which I don't want, so I want it to be done with only one element, and I have repeated my code in JS to display the circles.

Here is my current UI which I did by using two elements(ciclegraph, ciclegraph-two), I want to do it with only one element(ciclegraph), I'm not sure how to do it with only one element

[image: Here is m]

You can play with my code: https://jsfiddle.net/v5gz9xuk/1/

```js
const fakeData = [
  {
    _id: "6363d7c30741e9d8bfd189cd",
    index: 0,
    picture:
      "http://atlas-content-cdn.pixelsquid.com/stock-images/white-chair-1VrZXD0-600.jpg",
    age: 25,
  },
  {
    _id: "6363d7c33dab3e7ff64e1a70",
    index: 1,
    picture:
      "http://atlas-content-cdn.pixelsquid.com/stock-images/white-chair-1VrZXD0-600.jpg",
    age: 20,
  },
  {
    _id: "6363d7c3b36f17137195b4ff",
    index: 2,
    picture:
      "http://atlas-content-cdn.pixelsquid.com/stock-images/white-chair-1VrZXD0-600.jpg",
    age: 37,
  },
    {
    _id: "6363d7c3b36f17137195b4ff",
    index: 2,
    picture:
      "http://atlas-content-cdn.pixelsquid.com/stock-images/white-chair-1VrZXD0-600.jpg",
    age: 37,
  },
    {
    _id: "6363d7c3b36f17137195b4ff",
    index: 2,
    picture:
      "http://atlas-content-cdn.pixelsquid.com/stock-images/white-chair-1VrZXD0-600.jpg",
    age: 37,
  },
    {
    _id: "6363d7c3b36f17137195b4ff",
    index: 2,
    picture:
      "http://atlas-content-cdn.pixelsquid.com/stock-images/white-chair-1VrZXD0-600.jpg",
    age: 37,
  },
    {
    _id: "6363d7c3b36f17137195b4ff",
    index: 2,
    picture:
      "http://atlas-content-cdn.pixelsquid.com/stock-images/white-chair-1VrZXD0-600.jpg",
    age: 37,
  },  {
    _id: "6363d7c3b36f17137195b4ff",
    index: 2,
    picture:
      "http://atlas-content-cdn.pixelsquid.com/stock-images/white-chair-1VrZXD0-600.jpg",
    age: 37,
  },  {
    _id: "6363d7c3b36f17137195b4ff",
    index: 2,
    picture:
      "http://atlas-content-cdn.pixelsquid.com/stock-images/white-chair-1VrZXD0-600.jpg",
    age: 37,
  },  {
    _id: "6363d7c3b36f17137195b4ff",
    index: 2,
    picture:
      "http://atlas-content-cdn.pixelsquid.com/stock-images/white-chair-1VrZXD0-600.jpg",
    age: 37,
  },  {
    _id: "6363d7c3b36f17137195b4ff",
    index: 2,
    picture:
      "http://atlas-content-cdn.pixelsquid.com/stock-images/white-chair-1VrZXD0-600.jpg",
    age: 37,
  },  {
    _id: "6363d7c3b36f17137195b4ff",
    index: 2,
    picture:
      "http://atlas-content-cdn.pixelsquid.com/stock-images/white-chair-1VrZXD0-600.jpg",
    age: 37,
  },  {
    _id: "6363d7c3b36f17137195b4ff",
    index: 2,
    picture:
      "http://atlas-content-cdn.pixelsquid.com/stock-images/white-chair-1VrZXD0-600.jpg",
    age: 37,
  },  {
    _id: "6363d7c3b36f17137195b4ff",
    index: 2,
    picture:
      "http://atlas-content-cdn.pixelsquid.com/stock-images/white-chair-1VrZXD0-600.jpg",
    age: 37,
  },  {
    _id: "6363d7c3b36f17137195b4ff",
    index: 2,
    picture:
      "http://atlas-content-cdn.pixelsquid.com/stock-images/white-chair-1VrZXD0-600.jpg",
    age: 37,
  },
];



const displayImages = (data) => {

  let angle = 360 - 90;
  let dangle = 360 / 3;
    let dangle2 = 360 / 10;
  let sortingData = data.sort((a, b) => a.age - b.age);
  for (let i = 0; i < sortingData.length; ++i) {
     let circleDiv = document.createElement("div");
    if (i < 3) {
      angle += dangle;
      circleDiv.style.transform = `rotate(${angle}deg) translate(${200}px) rotate(${-angle}deg)`;
      circleDiv.classList.add("circle");
      circleDiv.innerHTML = `<img src=${sortingData[i].picture} alt="" />`;

      document.querySelector(".ciclegraph").appendChild(circleDiv);
    } else {
      angle += dangle2;
      circleDiv.style.transform = `rotate(${angle}deg) translate(${600}px) rotate(${-angle}deg)`;

      circleDiv.classList.add("circle");
      circleDiv.innerHTML = `<img src=${sortingData[i].picture} alt="" />`;

      document.querySelector(".ciclegraph-two").appendChild(circleDiv);
    }
}
}

displayImages(fakeData)
```

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  align-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.ciclegraph {
  position: absolute;
  width: 60%;
  margin: calc(100px / 2 + 0px);
  animation: rotate 200s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: rotate 200s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: rotate 200s linear infinite;
}
.ciclegraph .circle img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: calc(-100px / 2);
}
.ciclegraph:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: calc(100% - 2px * 2);
  height: calc(100% - 2px * 2);
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.ciclegraph-two {
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  /* height: 1000px; */
  margin: calc(100px / 2 + 0px);
  animation: rotate 170s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: rotate 170s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: rotate 170s linear infinite;
  transition-delay: calc(1005s);
}


.ciclegraph-two:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  /* border: 2px solid teal; */
  width: calc(100% - 2px * 2);
  height: calc(100% - 2px * 2);
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.ciclegraph-two .circle img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: calc(-100px / 2);
  /* background: teal;
  border-radius: 50%; */
}
```

```html
    <div class="main">
      <div class="ciclegraph"></div>
      <div class="ciclegraph-two"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You are calculating the angle already, why don't you calculate the coordinates for each item & just put it in absolute position ? The formula is something like: `x = Math.sin(angle) * radius + centerX; y = Math.cos(angle) * radius + centerY`. Where you can do it for multiple radiuses.

Comment: @OlegImanilov can you please give me some more details about where I will get the radius and centerX,centerZ value and do I need to use it Like this way? `transform: translateX(x) translateY:(Y)`,

Comment: I mean move the logic mainly into JS not CSS. You define the center & 2 radiuses.